# Delete characters from a column 'n' characters after the given condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, substring

I want to delete everything in this column 3 characters after '18'

```
MGL18JUNFUT
NATIONALUM18JUNFUT
NTPC18JUNFUT
ONGC18JUNFUT
PCJEWELLER18JUNFUT
PEL18JUNFUT
PFC18JUNFUT
PIDILITIND18JUNFUT
POWERGRID18JULFUT
PTC18JULFUT
RAYMOND18JULFUT
RBLBANK18JULFUT
RECLTD18JULFUT
RPOWER18JULFUT
MGL18JUN800PE
```

I want my output to look like

```
MGL18JUN
NATIONALUM18JUN
NTPC18JUN
ONGC18JUN
PCJEWELLER18JUN
PEL18JUN
PFC18JUN
PIDILITIND18JUN
POWERGRID18JUL
PTC18JUL
RAYMOND18JUL
RBLBANK18JUL
RECLTD18JUL
RPOWER18JUL
MGL18JUN
```

I have tried the following code.

```
output <- sub('(^.*?)18???.*', '' , df$column)
```

But the output is coming

```
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUNFUT
8JUN800PE
```

Excel equivalent for this is.

```
=LEFT(A1, FIND("18",A1,1) +4)
```

I have tried many other options like sub, gregexpr , substr but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could change the `sub` by capturing the pattern of characters (`.*` followed by 18 and then zero to three characters (`.{0,3}` or specifically 3 characters (`.{3}`) in a group (`(...)`) and replace by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("^(.*18.{0,3}).*", "\\1", df$column)
```

or

```
sub("^(.*18.{3}).*", "\\1", df$column)
#[1] "MGL18JUN"        "NATIONALUM18JUN" "NTPC18JUN"       "ONGC18JUN"      
#[5] "PCJEWELLER18JUN" "PEL18JUN"        "PFC18JUN"        "PIDILITIND18JUN"
#[9] "POWERGRID18JUL"  "PTC18JUL"        "RAYMOND18JUL"    "RBLBANK18JUL"   
#[13] "RECLTD18JUL"     "RPOWER18JUL"     "MGL18JUN"
```

Based on the OP's comments, if there are multiple instances of 18

```
v1 <- "PIDILITIND18JUN1180CE"
sub("^(.*?18.{3}).*", "\\1", v1)
```

It would also work on the initial data

```
sub("^(.*?18.{3}).*", "\\1", df$column)
#[1] "MGL18JUN"        "NATIONALUM18JUN" "NTPC18JUN"       "ONGC18JUN"      
#[5] "PCJEWELLER18JUN" "PEL18JUN"        "PFC18JUN"        "PIDILITIND18JUN"
#[9] "POWERGRID18JUL"  "PTC18JUL"        "RAYMOND18JUL"    "RBLBANK18JUL"   
#[13] "RECLTD18JUL"     "RPOWER18JUL"     "MGL18JUN"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(column = c("MGL18JUNFUT", "NATIONALUM18JUNFUT", 
"NTPC18JUNFUT", "ONGC18JUNFUT", "PCJEWELLER18JUNFUT", "PEL18JUNFUT", 
"PFC18JUNFUT", "PIDILITIND18JUNFUT", "POWERGRID18JULFUT", "PTC18JULFUT", 
"RAYMOND18JULFUT", "RBLBANK18JULFUT", "RECLTD18JULFUT", "RPOWER18JULFUT", 
"MGL18JUN800PE")), .Names = "column", class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Comment: Beat me to it! I think the range quantifier needs to be `{0,3}` based on OP using `???` in their regex?

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut  It could be the case, although there is no strings that shows that case

Comment: @AmanNangia  What is this data?  Based on the example you provided, the solution is matching with the expected output

Comment: It is not clear from the comments what you expect.  Also, based on the original question, multiple answers were already provided.  If you change the question now to include more conditions, it is a bit harsh for the people who answered it

Comment: @akrun but if the field has two '18' like input `PIDILITIND18JUN1180CE` then the output is `PIDILITIND18JUN1180CE` . How do we take the first 18 and delete everything after it?

Comment: @AmanNangia  I don't see any difference in the input and output.  Please check your comment

Comment: @AmanNangia Try `sub("^(.*[A-Z]18.{3}).*", "\\1", v1)#[1] "PIDILITIND18JUN"` where `v1 <- "PIDILITIND18JUN1180CE"`

Comment: @akrun this is the actual issue I am facing. I wanted output to be `PIDILITIND18JUN` but since the input had two instances of  '18' it is removing the characters after the second instance of '18'

Comment: @AmanNangia  Please check the above comment code.  It should work for it.  Regular expressions are based on patterns.  The earlier matches were based on the characters you showed.

Comment: @akrun thanks mate it worked for `PIDILITIND18JUN1180CE` since the second instance had a number before the '18' but in a case like `POWERGRID18JUN185PE` the output remains the same since the second '18' also had alphabets before it. Sorry for adding more conditions to my questions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AmanNangia  Please check my updated solution in the post `sub("^(.*?18.{3}).*", "\\1", v1)#
[1] "POWERGRID18JUN"` it works for these cases

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `stringr::str_extract`

```
stringr::str_extract(string, "(.*)18\\w{3}")
```

**Logic:**

**str_extract** extracts the regex (regular expression match). Here I am trying to match everything (using .*, `.` means any character and * matches zero or more character) till 18 then extracting 3 letters(consists of alphabets and numbers, using \w with {3}), also please note in case you do want it to extract between 1 to 3 you can use {m,n}, where m suggests minimum number of match, and n suggests maximum number of match. **An example**: \w{2,3} would match any string with 2 or 3 alphabets and so on. You can use `help(regex)` to have detailed understanding for the same. Thanks. I hope this is helpful.

**Output:**

```
#> stringr::str_extract(string, "(.*)18\\w{3}")
# [1] "MGL18JUN"        "NATIONALUM18JUN" "NTPC18JUN"       "ONGC18JUN"      
# [5] "PCJEWELLER18JUN" "PEL18JUN"        "PFC18JUN"        "PIDILITIND18JUN"
# [9] "POWERGRID18JUL"  "PTC18JUL"        "RAYMOND18JUL"    "RBLBANK18JUL"   
# [13] "RECLTD18JUL"     "RPOWER18JUL"     "MGL18JUN"
```

**Input:**

```
string <- c("MGL18JUNFUT",
"NATIONALUM18JUNFUT",
"NTPC18JUNFUT",
"ONGC18JUNFUT",
"PCJEWELLER18JUNFUT",
"PEL18JUNFUT",
"PFC18JUNFUT",
"PIDILITIND18JUNFUT",
"POWERGRID18JULFUT",
"PTC18JULFUT",
"RAYMOND18JULFUT",
"RBLBANK18JULFUT",
"RECLTD18JULFUT",
"RPOWER18JULFUT",
"MGL18JUN800PE")
```

**EDIT**:-

---

If you have multiple 18s in your data and wanted to match till first 18 then you can stop the greediness of regex character `*` by using `?` , like below:

```
stringr::str_extract(string, "(.*?)18\\w{3}")
```

Answer (score 3):

***EDIT:*** Have seen in comment section that OP is saying OP needs 3 characters after 1st occurrence of `18` itself then I am proposing this look forward regex for same now.

```
x <- c("MGL18JUNFUT","NATIONALUM18JUNFUT18SHDGUDDG","NTPC18JUNFUT","ONGC18JUNFUT","PCJEWELLER18JUNFUT","PEL18JUNFUT","PFC18JUNFUT","PIDILITIND18JUNFUT","POWERGRID18JULFUT","PTC18JULFUT","RAYMOND18JULFUT","RBLBANK18JULFUT","RECLTD18JULFUT","RPOWER18JULFUT","MGL18JUN800PE")
> 
regmatches(x,regexpr("(.*?)18.{3}",x))
```

Output will be as follows.

```
> regmatches(x,regexpr("(.*?)18.{3}",x))
 [1] "MGL18JUN"        "NATIONALUM18JUN" "NTPC18JUN"       "ONGC18JUN"      
 [5] "PCJEWELLER18JUN" "PEL18JUN"        "PFC18JUN"        "PIDILITIND18JUN"
 [9] "POWERGRID18JUL"  "PTC18JUL"        "RAYMOND18JUL"    "RBLBANK18JUL"   
[13] "RECLTD18JUL"     "RPOWER18JUL"     "MGL18JUN"       
>
```

---

Taking an example of vector you could use data frame too here.

```
x <- c("MGL18JUNFUT","NATIONALUM18JUNFUT","NTPC18JUNFUT","ONGC18JUNFUT","PCJEWELLER18JUNFUT","PEL18JUNFUT","PFC18JUNFUT","PIDILITIND18JUNFUT","POWERGRID18JULFUT","PTC18JULFUT","RAYMOND18JULFUT","RBLBANK18JULFUT","RECLTD18JULFUT","RPOWER18JULFUT","MGL18JUN800PE")
```

Following is the code on this.

```
regmatches(x,regexpr("^.*18.{3}",x))
```

Output will be as follows.

```
> regmatches(x,regexpr("^.*18.{3}",x))
 [1] "MGL18JUN"        "NATIONALUM18JUN" "NTPC18JUN"       "ONGC18JUN"      
 [5] "PCJEWELLER18JUN" "PEL18JUN"        "PFC18JUN"        "PIDILITIND18JUN"
 [9] "POWERGRID18JUL"  "PTC18JUL"        "RAYMOND18JUL"    "RBLBANK18JUL"   
[13] "RECLTD18JUL"     "RPOWER18JUL"     "MGL18JUN"       
>
```